# Multiple installations of Global site tag (gtag.js) detected

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, gtag.js

I have added the gtag like following

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-189297876-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x');
  gtag('config', 'G-xxxxxxxxxx');
  gtag('config', 'AW-xxxxxxxxx');
</script>
```

Here I use the Google Analytics, the AdWords Conversion and the Global-ID.

When I check it with the Google Tag Assistant Plugin of Chrome, I get

[image]

I don't know, if this is a problem (the Message "Multiple installations of Global site tag (gtag.js) detected"). Is it only there one time.

Comment: I agree, it is confusing as the way you have it is the most optimal way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your website is SPA (Single Page Application) it is a normal (known) behavior of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the Google Ads key to your `gtag.js` configuration

```
gtag('config', 'AW-xxxxxxxxxx');
```

it automatically adds a new  tag to your DOM like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-XXXXXXX&amp;l=dataLayer&amp;cx=c"></script>
```

I'd know why but it is. I found it with trial and error ;)